# How to configure WSO2 API Manager 2.1.0 to work with Identity Server 5.3.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I made the whole configuration of this link:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+WSO2+Identity+Server+as+a+Key+Manager

and now I get this error when I make a request for my API:

```
<ams:fault xmlns:ams="http://wso2.org/apimanager/security">
    <ams:code>900908</ams:code>
    <ams:message>Resource forbidden </ams:message>
    <ams:description>Access failure for API: /test/1.0.0, version: 1.0.0 status: (900908) - Resource forbidden </ams:description>
</ams:fault>
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [error code and message](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Error+Handling), it is due to accessing an unsubscribed resource. [This](https://medium.com/@sidath/resource-forbidden-403-in-wso2-api-manager-d7ad01ab6038) blog explains more. Make sure the user subscribed to the resource

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to not having a subscription for the API you are trying to invoke. You need to subscribe to the API before invoking it. You can follow https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Quick+Start+Guide#QuickStartGuide-InvokingyourfirstAPI to see how to subscribe and invoke an API.

Also make sure to invoke by giving the correct access token (the access token of the application you used to subscribe for the API).

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the same error even after having a valid subscription for the API, check whether `Advance Throttling` is enabled from IS (IS-AS-KM). If so you have to disable it.
You can do it by editing `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/api-manager.xml` as follows;

```xml
<ThrottlingConfigurations>
        <EnableAdvanceThrottling>false</EnableAdvanceThrottling>
        ...
</ThrottlingConfigurations>
```